# Does express allow other controllers to run in between awaits?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express

Let's say I have a few routes defined in express.

```
app.get('/all', async (req, res) => {
  // foo, bar, baz are database calls
  // since they depend on one another, they are run sequentially with await
  const fooRes = await foo();
  const barRes = await bar(fooRes);
  const bazRes = await baz(barRes);

  res.send({data: [fooRes,barRes,bazRes]})
});

app.post('/foo', async (req, res) => {
  // updates foo
});

app.post('/bar', async (req, res) => {
  // updates bar
});

app.post('/baz', async (req, res) => {
  // updates baz
});
```

If a user requests `/all`, can another user update `/foo` while the `/all` handler is still await-ing from the result from `baz(bar)`? This would result in potentially stale/incorrect data coming back from the `/all` handler.

Conversely, if the database calls were not dependent on each other, and the 3 db calls were fired at the almost the same instant in the `/all` handler

```
app.get('/all', async (req, res) => {
  const data = await Promise.all([
    foo(),
    bar(),
    baz()
  ]);

  res.send({ data })
});

// ... /foo, /bar, /baz update routes as above
```

Let's assume user1's request for `/all` hits express first, before user2's update request on `/baz` does.

Is it correct to assume that user1's `baz()` function call definitely executes before user2's `/baz` update?

Is it possible that a freak latency spike when querying the db can cause user1's `/all` request to return the updated `baz` value? ie. user2's `/baz` update actually reaches the db before user1's `/all` read queries.

Comment: I can't see any reason it *wouldn't* do that. You wouldn't want it to default to "do nothing else until this request is fully handled" as that would kill the throughput of your server for anything involving I/O. If you need to do serialization, you'll probably need to do it on purpose.

Comment: Note this has nothing to do with promises / `async` functions, just asynchronous work. The same thing would happen with old-style Node.js callback-based responses: `fs.readFile("/some/file", (err, data) => { /* do something with data*/ res.send(/*...*/); });`